# Werster Digital WD20EZRX 2 TB drive not showing in Windows xp but detects in ROM

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, installation, partitioning

I have system with
Processor: core 2 quad q9650
Motherboard: Intel DG33FB mother
Ram: 4GB

I have dual operating system Windows Xp pro 32 bit and Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit operating system installed. I bought a WD 2tb hard drive for storage. First I install it on windows 7 and setup it with 4 equal partitions and its working fine. Now my problem is that when I boot into windows XP it is not showing the new hard drive and also not showing in Disk Manager. I try to format and partitioned the Drive with Windows XP setup CD but now success. On Windows 7 it works fine and not in XP. I tried everything but no success run all the utilities by WD. Help please....